# C# listbox add data from another form

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I'm a C# student and I'm a little stuck at on my midterm project.

I dropped my project and spec here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/eo5ishsvz4vn6uz/CE3F4nvgDf

If you run the program, it will come to the last area I left off at..

```
private void btnAddScore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {  
  tempScore = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);
  Form1.scoreList = tempScore; (was Form1.scoreList[i] = tempScore;)
  }
  txtScoresList.Text += Convert.ToString(tempScore) + " ";
}
```

There's a main form, a secondary add form, and a third and fourth form, all the controls are in place, just the wiring is what's left over.

(1) In the above code, there are supposed to be 3 scores passed to the main form, which, along with a student name string, are to populate the ListBox on the main form. I can't figure out how to access that ListBox, anytime I type "listStudents" nothing happens.

(2) I'm also not sure how to limit an input of only 3 scores when I'm clicking the "add" button 1 time, which means I know my for loop is probably completely wrong. I don't know if I should save those scores to an array, list, or individual vars, being that it can be 3 (or more, but 3 is fine) scores.

(3) When I hit "OK" on the AddNewStudent form, do I write my code there to populate the main form ListBox, or does it go in the main form?

Update:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbStudents.Items.Clear();
    //something like
    foreach (decimal i in scoreList2)
        {
            scoreList = scoreList2.ToString(); //gives me a cannot implicitly convert error
        }
    lbStudents.Items.Add(tempInfo1 + " " + scoreList2);
}
//I want the listbox to populate like "Name - |100| |90| |80|"
```

This code seems to me, to be correct, for getting the ListBox populated, but I'm unsure of how to add the entire contents of the list to a string, and then add that to the listbox.

Answer (score 0):

This will get your code building and running.

Change the following declaration in form1

```
public static decimal[] scoreList = new decimal[3];
```

to

```
public static List<decimal> scoreList = new List<decimal>();
```

and update your btnAddScore_Click handler to

```
 //save scores to temp static var, populate noread txtbox txtScoresList with scores
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{   
    //save score to static var for trans-form data sending      
    tempScore = Convert.ToDecimal(txtScore.Text);
    Form1.scoreList.Add(tempScore);

}
```

The rest is not too difficult, you should be able to work it out.